# LINQ RemoveAll instead of loops

Tags: c#, linq

I have two for loops to remove item from the list. I am looking for an equivalent LINQ statement for these loops

```
for (Int32 i = points.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    for (Int32 j = touchingRects.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        if (touchingRects[j].HitTest(points[i], rect.TopEdge.Y1))
        {
            points.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

So far I am able to do this but the compiler doesn't understand this code:

```
points.RemoveAll(p => touchingRects.Where(r => r.HitTest(p, r.TopEdge.Y1)));
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please gives the compiler error that you are receiving.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The delegate that you pass into [`RemoveAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a.aspx) needs to return a bool.

I think you what to do this:

```
points.RemoveAll(p => touchingRects.Any(r => r.HitTest(p, r.TopEdge.Y1)));
```

Or possibly this (if the variable `rect` is actually defined elsewhere):

```
points.RemoveAll(p => touchingRects.Any(r => r.HitTest(p, rect.TopEdge.Y1)));
```

I should point out that your original code has the potential for some very strange behavior. After you remove an item from the list in your inner loop, you continue looping through `touchingRects` with the same index `i`. This can lead to some unexpected results. There probably should be a `break` in there somewhere, but you may have omitted from your question it for brevity. In any case, using this code fixes that problem.

Comment: Not working! The count of points is same before and after this statement.